# bash ssh broken pipe 22 retry command

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

I have a program where I am ssh'ing to several Virtual Machines, and executing a script from each virtual machine in parallel until they are both finished. The command is as follows:

```
nohup ssh -T username@VM1 << EOF1 &
cd ${path1}
nohup bash ${path1}/script1.sh &
EOF1
nohup ssh -T username@VM2 << EOF2 &
cd ${path1}
nohup bash ${path1}/script2.sh &
EOF2
wait
echo "done"
```

Currently, with this program it will ssh to VM1 and run script1.sh, while simultaneously ssh to VM2 and run script2.sh. However, sometimes, there is an error:

```
Connection closed by xxx.xx.xx.x port 22
```

This error is very sporadic, shows no signs of a pattern, and can happen multiple times in succession (the most I have seen is 3, but doesn't mean 4 or 5 are impossible). I ssh to each individual virtual machine to run intensive programs that require lots of RAM, so running everything on the same VM is impossible with strict time constraints.

The problem is there are downstream programs that rely on the output from these two commands and if these commands do not ssh properly, they cannot run the scripts and the downstream processes produce undesired errors. Therefore, is there a way to rerun the command if the ssh throws the port 22 issue? I know there is an 'until' command, but cannot seem to get it to work properly with the other command-line arguments I have passed.

Comment: You can capture error in a variable and execute command in loop